# Displaying a .pdf in WebBroser WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, pdf, webbrowser-control

I have an application which has a listbox. When an item in the list is clicked the app takes us to a new page with a web browser which displays the contents of that particular item (we get these from a particular list which is previously parsed xml data) in a web browser (because they also contain html elements). This all works perfectly fine.
Now, there are a few items in the list which contain a link. The link displays in the browser and when clicked it takes us to a .pdf file (still in the webbrowser) which is not being displayed.
What I now wonder is:

1. How to check if the link is being clicked? Is there an event for that?
2. How can I display the .pdf within the webbrowser control without the aid of other application?

Thank you,
Should you need any code that's currently working and written just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if the link is clicked, you can use the `Navigating` event of the webbrowser.

Unfortunately, you can't use the webbrowser to display the PDF. You'll have to use a [`WebBrowserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instead.

To sum it up, in your case you can use the `Navigating` event to detect the click on the link (since it's apparently important from you), then cancel the navigation (by setting `e.Cancel = true` in the event handler), then call the `WebBrowserTask` to display the PDF document.

Comment: Yes sure I could use Navigating, but I need to check if the link ends with .pdf. That's why I want to have a method that fires when a link is clicked. Now I'm trying to get the actual uri and I get a "It is invalid to use this property or method during a Navigating event handler." when I try "browser.Source.toString()" during the Navigating method.

Comment: Use `e.Url` to retrieve the URL during the `Navigating` event